# Azure on prem data gateway for logic app sign in account

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps, onpremises-gateway

I have a customer server, who does not want us to access their server but to connect the logic app to the server I need to install the on prem data gateway and configure it. I have created a user in active directory for the respective subscription with contributor access. I don’t want to share these details to the customer to enter while configuring the data gateway as they can use the same to login. What shall I do now ?

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest just having a logmein or teamviewer session with them when they are installing the data gateway, so that you can type in the credentials.

if this is not possible, may I suggest you try to give them an aad account to install the gateway as, then after the gateway is installed, change the account password 
Please Note: I have not tested this second option, and there does not appear to be any specific documentation about that account, but there is no indication that it needs to be active or password must be current.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I’ll try that and let here know if that works.